# Question Filtering Feature Request

Tags: feature-request

Is there any option about filtering Questions in different ways?
if yes, How ?

---

if No, Please read following

---

I think there should be an option for an advance search in SO. ( I am just suggesting )

For example.
I want to find out

"A question having tag about UISearchBar && having more than 2 Votes || Answered By Sir Skit || Having bounty && Bounty >100 "

"A question having more than 100 views ? "

"A question having more than 10 answers ? "

If this kind of facility SO Provides, their users might find out information, quickly.

The reason behind this,
"There will be no repeat question." - (As user can find out the info. easily).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the advanced search options which will allow you to do many of the things you are looking for.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search

Comment: That's why you ask and we tell :)